# How can I access previous checked in versions of workspace repositroy?

Tags: rtc

How can I access previous checked in versions of workspace repository?

I just seem to be able to compare against the latest changes sets delivered to the stream. Can I also view/compare previous version of a file which has been checked into my repository workspace ?

Answer (score 1):

You can display the history of a file checked in by right-clicking on ("Show History").
From there, in the "History" view, you can right-click on any version and select "Compare to" with any other version (not just the previous one).

As [explained in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/67501/can-i-set-the-file-back-to-a-previous-version), you can access (open) the content of any older version you want, which gives you the opportunity of replacing the current version with said content, should you want to revert back for just one file.

Rolling back would be a slightly different issue:

> If the change set that created the current version contains only that version, then you can replace the current version with the previous version by discarding that change set.
>
> But if that change-set modifies multiple versions, you cannot roll back just that file. [Work Item 59688](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=59688) requests the ability to "split" a change set, so you can move this change into it's own separate change set (and then you could roll back the change to just that file).

---

Note that the history will be by default the one for that given file done in your repo workspace (checkins) or in your stream (deliver).
The same "show history" done at the *Component* level (when you right click on a Component, in the "Components" section, and select "Show Repository files", would give the full history (done on any Stream), but wouldn't display the history done on repo workspace (chekins).

Note also that only RTC4.0 has ["Checkin history"](https://jazz.net/library/article/191/)

> This is essentially the history of a file within a change set.
>
> Each time you check-in a file into a change set, the content is stored in the repository. Normally you see only the final version of a file within the change set. But sometimes you want to go back and see what the intermediate versions of the file were. Check-in History is an expansion of the changes made to the file each time it was checked into a change set.